# Scala add method in extend something

Tags: scala, syntax

I made lowerBound method in my BinarySearchTree.

BinarySearchTree extends TreeMap[Int, Int].

So I made lowerBound method in BinarySearchTree.

but compiler said

```
treetest.scala:85: error: value lowerNeighbor is not a member of TreeMap[Int,Int] t2.lowerNeighbor(3)
```

How to made it? :)

```
class BinarySearchTree(private val root: Node) extends TreeMap[Int, Int] {

  def lowerNeighbor(x : Int) : Int = {
    var t = root
.........
   }
}


var t2: TreeMap[Int, Int] = new BinarySearchTree
t2.lowerNeighbor(3)
```

Comment: Can provide more code snippets? For instance can you show where you defined `lowerNeighbor` and how you instantiate `t2`?

Comment: What about the type "Node" where do you get that from? Remember that the tree is immutable, so if you extend an empty TreeMap every operation you perform will create a new TreeMap and NOT a BinarySearchTree. Unless you specify it of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your `t2` variable to be of the static type `TreeMap[Int, Int]`. Therefore, for the compiler, each time you use `t2`, it will assume it is an instance of `TreeMap[Int, Int]`. `lowerNeighbor` is not a method defined on `TreeMap`s, but on `BinarySearchTree`s. The static type of your variable has to be `BinarySearchTree` if you want to call the `lowerNeighbor` method.*

<sub>* This is ignoring implicit conversions, which you may want to read up on once you've figured out the static type vs. dynamic type issue.</sub>